# Keep playing sound with MPMoviePlayerController and locked screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, mpmovieplayercontroller, core-audio

When you're watching a video with `MPMoviePlayerController` and the user presses the top button to lock the screen, the app goes to sleep and so does the sound from the video.

Is there any way to prevent the lock from stopping the sound?  If not, is there a way to intercept the lock, to create a "custom lock", to save some battery but keep playing the video?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you haven't [set your audio session category](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html).  Set the `AVAudioSession`'s `category` property to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` to indicate that the app's major purpose is to play back audio, and it therefore should ignore the screen lock button and ring/silent switch.  If you're working with the lower-level C API, you'll be using `AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback)`, but it's the same concept.

Comment: If this works for you, please add the core-audio tag to help people find the answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it is pretty helpful, however this is available from 3.0 and on, is there a way to do this in previous OS version?

Comment: The low-level C way of doing it is available all the way back to iPhone OS 2.0.  The Obj-C AVAudioSession is a convenience added in 3.0.

Comment: @invalidname: the solution seem correct but i am trying it on iOS 5, is that code still working?